# wordpress do_shortcode and Shareaholic plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to add Shareaholic recommendetions plugin in my template.

The results is always blank div...who can help me?

```
<div id="recommendations">
                <?php do_shortcode("shareaholic app='recommendations' id='xxxx'");?>
            </div>
```

Or:

```
<div id="recommendations">
                <?php global $wp_embed;
                      $post_embed = $wp_embed->run_shortcode('shareaholic app="recommendations" id="xxxx"');?>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_shortcode` needs to be echoed:

`echo do_shortcode( '[shareaholic app="test"]' );`